# java.net.SocketTimeoutException :Read timed out while trying to create App Engine Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, adt, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following a tutorial to create an app with App Engine as a backend and cloud endpoints. I am encountering a problem at the initial stage where I create the app engine backend for the client. The error log shows

"There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out". I had created an endpoint library previously but had to delete it because of some problem. But now I have made a new client app and created the app engine backend on that. Don't know if the problem is because of deleting previous library endpoints.

It maybe a noob question but I'm not able to find any solution, hence this question here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, the endpoint library which is supposed to be created on the client application when the app engine is created does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to a complicated query. I was able to fix the problem with a simplification of the query.

Maybe you can post some code?